# Can I transfer an old Minecraft PS4 world in my cloud save data to Bedrock edition on my new PS4?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I just found all my Minecraft worlds from my first PS4 in my cloud saves, is it possible to download them and have them work on the Bedrock edition on my new PS4? I’ve downloaded the world and save datas, but they don’t show up on my bedrock world menu, nor is there an option to view any PS4 worlds. I also tried seeing if they’d show up in the Minecraft PS4 version through the “editions” section in the Bedrock menu to no avail. However in the Bedrock worlds menu there does appear to be some storage taken up by something, although I have no other worlds or save data currently on it. So is there any way to get this cloud world save data into the bedrock edition or the PS4 version accessible through bedrock? I’d really like to play on my old worlds that I thought were lost forever.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Just sign into your account on the new PS4 and download your saves from the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

yes, just as stated above you can but it is more complicated to do it that way and even though it rarely happens you do have a chance of the cloud deleting your saved data after a certain amount of time. if you still have your old ps4 i recommend getting a usb drive and go through your saved game files in the storage of your ps4 in the settings and download all your saved game data to the usb. from there you can go into your storage settings on the new ps4 and download all saved game data for minecraft there. this allows you to transfer data much easier and with a much less to no risk of loss of game data.